# 'Expected primary expression' when expanding C Macro

Tags: c++, struct, aggregate, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I'm trying to default initialize a config struct that consists of some fields including another subordinate config struct - with a macro:

[LiveDemo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBIAzKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BekkpjgJBIeEsUTFc8XaYDmlCBEzEBBk%2Bfly2mPZ5DDV1BAVhkdFxtrX1jVktCsM9wX3FA2UAlLaoXsTI7BzmscHI3lgA1CaxbsgT%2BKiH2CYaAIJXt2axWDQhewCyAJpuAddCQgD6ABFsAAxa5yAIAFT%2BbgA8qFgQBJADiexYAE9aHgIiAQKgEh0FAcAOwWA4AVjcdz21L2ADomH8DrEAXszKRyZSbjS6RFGYcWfEOVSabSFF4IniCAo%2Bcy3p9vr9ASCwZC/kI5BYYcoobD4ciIPMhTcTESAXdzQ8ntM5V8fv8gaDwVD1ZrtdC4YiUejMdiQGLeZK0oSTaSTBThdTacgZSywBxrnHDqHw1yRegY3s4wAJROxZOc26m83Gm7MNgKBJMNaojFY80kiN7CbELwOJviv6BgQKRshxvc5AIOp7aNJ/s0wfD9Nj1PUk1mvPF67c5utgh7LsMHuz4lWHfc4Lrhkz5fcmmHva8k9nmn%2Bzv4oPtiX46XXmnzk9LgcGBSE9E7Jhf17Bt9xpf8fwUCBN0JSUFHmccbxADcXz5ElkKlYkzVAucQNPG9uQQzCv3w6D0NfRcdw/CjCyw24bgvFgmGCA16z3PCax9HFwMAwkFFQNg/gA38IA%2BW1FQdFUdQ9fV5ng6iCJ3YhMAIFYGD2DRP1NDhFloTgyV4PwOC0UhUE4SlLGsJtllWTADgeHhSAITRtMWABrEBJCJWlYi4DQiQ0SQAE4ADYNAADliMkyRaXSOEkAznJMzheAUEANEc5zFjgWAYEQFB%2BISOhonISg0BYQr6BiYAuDMNksAANzwNYADU8EwAB3GEEkYTgHJoWgCGiVKIGxIzeAiYI6jRXreDKthBBhBhaGmsbSCwRijHEVb8CUqp6swVLVswVRKi8QbEsPNpEp9Ygpo8LBEoIYg8BYGbFioAxgAUVqOq6nruF4fhBBEMR2CkGRBEUFR1FW3QYsMYxrGsfQsVSyBFmgzgAFoAHUxFoPYsZhQksax05%2BVMCzLDMYyKiqZwIFcUZmlIQJpiKEpsmSVIBGZrncjSXoObmVp2mqSY%2BfGNpKg6Lp6iF/pSiGbpJeV%2BX2cViRFj4lY1i1/Q9IS1bTI4PZVDC4KseCyQ9mAZBkD2GraTMPYIFwQgSDsnz5l4Jyxtk0gEEwJgsBiA0Dbi3hXrJdLDOMk2UrSjL/dIbK8uWAgEjOkqIDKirolCVh1nNy3rdt%2B3HbMZ3eEwfAiGe9A9CB4RRHEcHm6htRErh0h2tuhI3oj/TSDj3gTZhM6s/XVAqDNi2rZtu2Hadl2IA8cqiuIL2uB95OtAD9yY4j%2BLSGj2PEoT2wk79/e3JAMkq%2BCsLArMQKY9iQKuGtyQwrJCPYiNvHZKe8XIRzMIAsewCb6gP2sQFIzhJBAA%3D%3D%3D)

```
#include <cstdio>

#define MYCLASS_DEFAULT_CONFIG mylib::options { \
    .a_ = 2, \
    .b_ = 3, \
    .subopts_ = MYCLASS_DEFAULT_SUBOPT_CONFIG() \
}

#define MYCLASS_DEFAULT_SUBOPT_CONFIG mylib::sub_options { \
    .c_ = 'A'; \
    .d_ = 'H'; \
}


namespace mylib
{
    struct sub_options
    {
        char c_;
        char d_;
    };

    struct options
    {
        int a_;
        int b_;
        sub_options subopts_;
    };


    class myclass
    {
        myclass(options opts)
            : opts_ { opts }
        {
            
        }

        options opts_;
    };
}

int main()
{
    mylib::myclass some_class(MYCLASS_DEFAULT_CONFIG());
    
    return 0;

}
```

I'm not really sure why that doesn't work as x86 gcc 12.2 gives me:

```
<source>:3:47: error: expected primary-expression before '{' token
    3 | #define MYCLASS_DEFAULT_CONFIG mylib::options { \
      |
```

What primary epression am I missing?

Comment: But why are you using macros at all?

Comment: Also, you are "calling" the macro like it was a parametrized macro. In any case, did you try manually replacing the macro name with the macro content? That should clarify the problem quickly.

Comment: @KamilCuk Please suggest a better C++ solution. I ported this from C code and it has to advantage of no runtime overhead. If something like this exists in C++, I'm more than happy to apply it. Keep in mind though I want to keep the options structs aggregates.

Comment: @glades If those values are de facto the default for `myclass`, then you can consider giving default value for `myclass::opts_`, or use default constructor for `myclass` to construct with default value, or give default argument to the constructor. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MdsGzehfv)

Comment: @glades If that is not the only default config, you can also consider using tag classes to dispatch to different behaviors: https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/04/27/tag-dispatching/

Answer (score 6):

```
.c_ = 'A'; \
```

List elements initialization are separated with a comma, not `;`. It's `{ .c_ = 'a', }`, no `;`, but with `,`.

```
#define MYCLASS_DEFAULT_CONFIG mylib::options { ... }

MYCLASS_DEFAULT_CONFIG()
```

The `()` are *taken literally* and are left as is. Your code becomes `mylib::options { ... }()` with a bogus `()` on the end. Either make a macro function `#define MYCLASS_DEFAULT_CONFIG()` or remove the `()`.

```
class myclass
{
    myclass()...
}

mylib::myclass
```

`myclass` constructor is private. You can't call it from main.

---

Anyway, why macros at all? Just use variables. Consider:

```
namespace mylib {
    struct sub_options {
        char c_;
        char d_;
    };
    struct options {
        int a_;
        int b_;
        sub_options subopts_;
    };
    class myclass {
        options opts_;
    public:
        myclass(options opts) : opts_{opts} {}
    };
    static constexpr mylib::sub_options sub_options_default{
        .c_ = 'A',
        .d_ = 'H',
    };
    static constexpr mylib::options myclass_default_config{ \
        .a_ = 2,
        .b_ = 3,
        .subopts_ = sub_options_default,
    };
}
int main() {
    mylib::myclass some_class(mylib::myclass_default_config);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that looks better! Why did you make the constexpr's static though?